# Running multiple batch files on different remote servers in a specific order

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, windows-server-2008, remote-access

I have some batch files which need to be run asynchronously in following order on 6 remote servers located on same network and all servers having common username & password to login. I have put **Master.bat** file on Server5.

```
STEP1 :Run file1.bat on 4 different servers (Server1, Server2, Server3, Server4) in parallel           
STEP2 :Run file2.bat on 2 different servers (Server5, Server6) in parallel                                                  
STEP3 :Run file3.bat on Server5 (which is local server in my case as Master.bat is on Server5 only )                                                                                      
STEP4 :Run file4.bat on 2 same servers as in STEP2 (Server5, Server6) in parallel                                   
STEP5 :Run file5.bat on 4 same servers as in STEP1 (Server1, Server2, Server3, Server4) in parallel
```

I have planned to do this as follows :

**Serverlist1.txt :**

```
Server1 ip
Server2 ip
Server3 ip
Server4 ip
```

**Serverlist2.txt :**

```
Server5 ip
Server6 ip
```

**Master.bat :**

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "delims= " %i in (C:\test\Serverlist1.txt) do ( psexec \\%i C:\test\file1.bat )
for /F "delims= " %i in (C:\test\Serverlist2.txt) do ( psexec \\%i C:\test\file2.bat )
call file3.bat
for /F "delims= " %i in (C:\test\Serverlist2.txt) do ( psexec \\%i C:\test\file4.bat )
for /F "delims= " %i in (C:\test\Serverlist1.txt) do ( psexec \\%i C:\test\file5.bat )
```

I havn't tested it yet so not sure whether multiple **FOR** loops in a **Master.bat** file will be waiting for each other to be finished or not ?. Should I put these **FOR** loops in other Batch files and them **CALL** them in **Master.bat** ? 
This all seems bit lengthy to me.Is there any simple method to do this ? 
Need help !

**EDIT1**

**file1.bat**

```
taskkill /f /im firefox.exe
net stop W3SVC
sc config W3SVC start= demand
net start W3SVC
```

I want file1.bat to wait until the "SUCCESS" signal is received.Where I should put `waitfor SUCCESS` command in file1.bat file ?

In above **Master.bat** file where I should insert `waitfor /SI SUCCESS` command to send a signal to **file1.bat** to start running ?

Actually I have to define different Signal Name for all the five batch files, sothat I can run them one after another as per 5 steps mentioned above.

Comment: Start batch files that need to run in parallel, in these batch, use waitfor command to wait for start signal and from master send signal to start waiting batchs.

Comment: MC..but can i call START directly through PSExec like...
`for /F "delims= " %i in (C:\test\list1.txt) do ( psexec \\%i start C:\test\file1.bat )` ?

Comment: ..and MC, also i am not getting how `waitfor` delay can be implemented for a set of servers on same domain..?..Whether in batch files `waitfor SUCCESS` and in Master file `waitfor /s Server5 /si SUCCESS` will do the work ? its not clear to me that how `waitfor` will work in my case as per your suggestion ?

Comment: Yes, you can use psexec, and it's a good option, but master will now wait for batch to end OR will wait and until one batch has finished, other will no start. Waitfor? Use psexec to start remote batchs, and in these batch files use waitfor to wait for master to send the signal to start working. So, all batch files start at the same time. And if you no use /S in waitfor, signal is send across domain.

Comment: MC..as you explained above .it seems like i don't need to maintain **Serverlist1.txt** and **Serverlist2.txt** while not using `/S in waitfor`...? as if signal is being sent across common domain then those servers will automatically identify the **SUCCESS** signal to start ..?

Comment: It depends on how you code your master. As i understand it, these txt files determine what to run and where. Not when to start.

Comment: Yes..correct..!but could you pls tell me where I should put `waitfor` command in **file1.bat** and **Master.bat** as per **EDIT1** in question..?

Answer (score 0):

a. One option is to run all commans on each server successively: eg: bat1 on Server1, S2, S3, S4,  bat2 on S5, S6, etc

b. If option a. does not fit to you, I don't see a simple solution:

1. Create a ServerlistX.txt file for each step (with necessary servers IP).
2. Set Step=0
3. **call** all servers for first step.
4. Monitor if all server batches completed successfully. Here you can set a specific window name and use `tasklist /FI ...` command to filter processes by name and window name, and close child windows. Waits between check can be emulated by **ping** command "`ping localhost>nul`". It will last ~ 3 sec.
5. Set Step=Step+1
6. Check if Step is not exceeding max and exit if so.
7. Goto step 3.

Comment: Mihai..thanks for your reply..but option b seems to be making it more complicated.