# Inserting 'waitfor' command in called and calling batch files

Tags: batch-file, wait, remote-access, psexec

I have 3 called batch files like called1.bat :

**called1.bat**

```
taskkill /f /im firefox.exe
net stop W3SVC
sc config W3SVC start= demand
net start W3SVC
```

and a calling Master.bat file which calles all the three called batch files as below:

**Master.bat**

```
@echo off 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM 1st for loop:
for /F "delims= " %i in (C:\test\Serverlist1.txt) do ( psexec \\%i start C:\data\called1.bat )
REM 2nd for loop:
for /F "delims= " %i in (C:\test\Serverlist2.txt) do ( psexec \\%i start C:\data\called2.bat )
REM 3rd for loop:
for /F "delims= " %i in (C:\test\Serverlist3.txt) do ( psexec \\%i start C:\data\called3.bat )
```

Actually I want to send different signals from Master.bat file to the three called.bat files to run them on some remote servers as below:

```
called1.bat file to wait until the "SIGNAL1" is received from Master.bat
called2.bat file to wait until the "SIGNAL2" is received from Master.bat
called3.bat file to wait until the "SIGNAL3" is received from Master.bat
```

Where I should put `waitfor SIGNAL1` command in **called1.bat** file ?

Where I should put `waitfor /SI SIGNAL1` command in **Master.bat** file to send the signal to called1.bat to start running ? and similarly for other files..

**My prime purpose here is:** In Master.bat file, `2nd for loop` should only start running once `1st for loop` completes its full execution and similarly `3rd for loop` after `2nd for loop`thats why preferring `waitfor SIGNAL` method so far.

Comment: @Endoro...Plz could you help me out here ?

Comment: @foxidrive..I would request your assistance too.

Comment: in a batch use for loop variables with double percent `%%i`. What is a _signal_ and how can the batch receive it?

Comment: I tried using [this link](http://ss64.com/nt/waitfor.html)..

Comment: @Endoro..[This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961541/running-multiple-batch-files-on-different-remote-servers-in-a-specific-order/20009061?noredirect=1#20009061) of mine would help you to understand my exact requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea can be:

In master.bat

```
for each server in list (
    create the remote process
    spawn a local copy of waitfor to know when remote ends
)
send signal to remote systems to start work
loop waiting for local waitfors to end on signals from remote servers
```

local copies of waitfor should be spawned as `start "" /b waitfor remoteserversignal" with remote server signal unique for each server, so we know when it has finished

tasklist / pslist / wmic can be used to know when local copies of wait for have finished.

In remote.bat

```
wait for master signal to start
do work
send signal to master to signal end of work
```

Comment: Thanks for the concept MC..! implemented successfully..:)